# get the histogram for gray-scale image in C++ in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

I am trying to get the histogram for grey scale images in order to determine if the image is dark, bright, low contrast etc.
Is there a function in c++ help doing this?

Comment: What did you try up to now?

Comment: i have tried `calcHist()` function but it is for RGB images

Comment: "it is for RGB images".... from [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d): "Each [input array] can have an arbitrary number of channels."

Answer (score 0):

It's rather well-explained here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dbc/tutorial_histogram_calculation.html

Just skip the RGB part as you load the image in grayscale. So, instead of:

```
Mat src = imread( samples::findFile( parser.get<String>( "@input" ) ), IMREAD_COLOR );
    if( src.empty() )
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    vector<Mat> bgr_planes;
    split( src, bgr_planes );
```

I'd do:

```
Mat src = imread( samples::findFile( parser.get<String>( "@input" ) ), IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
```

And instead of using all three planes from **bgr_planes** just use **src**.